# Databinding DataTable to DataGrid - Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have created `DataGrid` and I wan't to add DataTemplateColumns generic , so it depends on number of columns that Data table ,that I put as source , have!
But when i do all of that and bind `DataGrid` columns to `DataTable` columns i have scenario where i got right number of row in `DataGrid` , but it's data from first row only. So , what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code :

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new 
PropertyPath(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
binding.Source = dataTable

FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new 
FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
dataTemplate.VisualTree = textBlock;
dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
dgTab1.Columns.Add(dataGridTemplateColumn);
```

I think i have a problem with binding, but i don't know how to fix it, obviously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SetBinding` (instead of `SetValue`) method to bind to the `Text` property:

```
FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```